# How do I count the number of items with a specific column name from a Pandas df? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

```
    Pick    Tm  Player  Pos Age To  AP1 PB  St  CarAV   ... Att Yds TD  Rec Yds TD  Tkl Int Sk  College/Univ
0   1   CLE Myles Garrett   DE  21  2017    0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   13      5.0 Texas A&M
1   2   CHI Mitch Trubisky  QB  23  2017    0   0   1   0   ... 29  194 0   0   0   0               North Carolina
2   3   SFO Solomon Thomas  DE  21  2017    0   0   1   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   25      2.0 Stanford
3   4   JAX Leonard Fournette   RB  22  2017    0   0   1   0   ... 207 822 7   25  195 1               LSU
4   5   TEN Corey Davis WR  22  2017    0   0   1   0   ... 0   0   0   22  227 0               West. Michigan
```

Given this df, I want to count the number of players per `College/Univ`.
So, just in this particular df, all collegs will have the value of 1.

Given a df and a college name, how can I count the number of items?

Comment: Or `(df['College/Univ'] == 'Texas A&M').sum()` ?

Comment: You can do this. ```df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abssbab')})
df.groupby('a').count()```

Comment: (df['College/Univ'] == 'Texas A&M').sum() this worked~ Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create boolean mask and then count `True`s by `sum`, `True`s are processes like `1`s:

```
(df['College/Univ'] == 'Texas A&M').sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would like to extend my question a bit. How can I get the frequencies of all college names in the 'College/Univ' column? So like: `Texas A&M: 5, UC Berkeley: 4...`, given a dataframe and a column_name.

Comment: Yes, then need `df['count'] = df.groupby('College/Univ')['College/Univ'].transform('size')` if need new column or if need only counts use `df1 = df.groupby('College/Univ').size().reset_index(name='count')`

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I was looking for. Does pandas also provide functionality for making this into a matplotlib bar chart?

Comment: Sure, then need `df.groupby('College/Univ').size().plot.bar()`